# Access website on a local IIS from a mobile phone

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking, localserver

I uploaded my ASP.NET website on local IIS server 
I'm using windows 8.1 pro and would like to access the website through another PC and a mobile phone (windows phone or android)
I would like to know how to configure my network and my server to do though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appreantly my stupid bitdefender was the problem although I tried disabling it's firewall but appreantly it doesn't stop giving the last piece of himself until you completly uninstall it
thanks again for trying to help

Answer (score 4):

First, both devices should be in the same network. Then hit windows key and type "Windows Defender Firewall". In advance settings, you can add a new Inbound rule. Next, select the port option and give your port number. After creating a new Inbound rule you can connect using the IP address and port. `eg: 192.168.8.102:8000`

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to find your iis machines' ip address - you can use service like:http://www.whatismyip.com/
2. open your firewall port for whatever port you set for the website in iis. (Firewall port opening tutorial:http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)
3. then on your another pc or mobile, just navigate using the ip you found on setp 1 with the port number you set on iis.

Comment: the 2 devices are connected on the same local network so I guess I wont be needing my global IP. I already forwarded port 80 used by IIS but when I try to type my local IP on the browser it displays "web page can't be displayed" @Alan

Answer (score 0):

I was using `MachineName:Port`, thus was not working. When using `MachineIP:Port` it works, however. I found that mobile cannot resolve the ip of machine using its name, as a normal PC can do (PC's Chrome works using machine name, but Android's one does not work unless using explicit IP).